# Mobile app release strategy best practice

Tags: deployment

I am developing a mobile app with backend and wondering what's the best practice or guidance on mobile app and backend (developed with .netcore and deployed in Azure) release.

My current issue is that because mobile app requires review process and during the review process, it is expected that the backend has been deployed (correct me if I am wrong). If there are some breaking changes in the backend, then during the review process, users using the older mobile app may experience some issues.

My idea on the strategy could be

1. during the backend development, I always need to keep it backward compatible to avoid any breaking changes (is it possible to avoid all the breaking changes?)
2. create two backend production environments and deploy backend to different production environments alternatively. When deploy the mobile app, it uses different production environments alternatively as well.

Not sure if there is any commonly used best practices on this? Thank you